# How to solve $y'' + y = y^{-3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I am trying to solve a central force problem and came to an equation like this:

$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + y = \frac{1}{y^3}$$

I can't find a decent method to solve it.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Offhand I don't know what the answer is, but as for a method to solve it, there is no conceptual problem - $y$ and $x$ are easily separated, then it's just a question of integrating twice.

Comment: Separating won't help, since it is second order.  Your best bet would be an approximation technique, like asymptotics.  It is an autonomous equation, if that helps.

Comment: yes, I don't think I would be able to seperate y and x successfully in this equation

Comment: @Physics_Plasma I think Suzu means "use the transformation $y''= \mathrm{d}_y ((y')^2/2)$" even though this is the wrong name for it.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this equation has special solutions when $y'\equiv 0$ ($y=\pm 1, y=\pm i$). Let us look for such solutions that $y'$ does not vanish identically. Let us multiply both sides of the equation by $y'$:

$y'y''+yy'=\frac{y'}{y^3}$,

or

$\frac{1}{2}((y')^2)'+\frac{1}{2}(y^2)'=-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{y^2})'$,

or

$(y')^2+y^2=-\frac{1}{y^2}+C$.

Now it is easy to separate $y$ and $x$.